# Sharing refresh tokens and client Ids

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

This questions might have been already asked but I don't see much info on `refresh_token` sharing.

So we are using [Azure Native API to Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#native-application-to-web-api) scenario to authenticate users. 
My client machine will have a python script which when executed will authenticate users and generates `access_token` and `refresh_token`. To do this the scripts have `client_id` of native app (No need of `client_secret` for native app). Once authenticated we use the tokens to access the web-api.

**Question:** Since the client app has all these info, if user hacks into the code and gains access to `client_id`, `access_token` and `refresh_token` can he use them to generate tokens and access the web API?

Though we make `access_token` shortlived to 10mins, if he gets hold of `client_id` and `refresh_token` can he generate as many tokens he wants and access web API. Will the `refresh_token` from one machine work on another machine. I can't find any documentation from Microsoft that says `refresh_tokens` are bound to a machine based on IP or MAC or something

Answer (score 1):

These are what they call as bearer tokens. If the tokens get hacked then there is no security. Bearer tokens have to be transmitted via ssl and stored securely.

Comment: Stored securely? The client application sits on client machine so how can we store it securely? That is my concern

Comment: See "OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations" RFC, in particular the "Threat: Obtaining Refresh Tokens" section https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6819#page-17

Comment: Each platform has recommended storage to store the tokens. In case of web browsers localstorage is good.